# Configure grub2 to use a keyfile to unlock luks encrypted / and /boot

Tags: grub2, opensuse, luks

I'm using *openSUSE* and want to use full disk encryption and a USB device with a keyfile to decrypt the system.
My whole system is encrypted in the same *LUKS* container (including `/boot`).
Because `/boot` is encrypted, grub2 asks for a password to decrypt it. Once I provide the password to grub, initrd is able to decrypt the system using the keyfile `/dev/disk/by-partlabel/key`, but grub still needs the password to get to the initrd phase.

**How can I configure grub2 to use that keyfile so that the password is not required?** This computer will be accessed via ssh and a keyboard and monitor will not be available. If required I can put the keyfile into a proper filesystem instead of using a key-partition.

I need `/boot` to be encrypted with the rest of the system so that it can be snapshoted along with the rest of the btrfs filesystem and the whole OS, kernel included, can be restored to a working state should anything break.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not officially available as far as I know.

You can take a look at [this site](https://grub.johnlane.ie/):  (and the corresponding [git repository](https://github.com/johnlane/grub)).

> The Grub cryptomount command can mount LUKS volumes. **This extension
> augments that capability with support for detached headers and key
> files** as well as adding support for plain DMCrypt volumes.
>
> This makes it possible to boot from LUKS and DMCrypt volumes. The LUKS
> header may be detached and stored on a separate device such as a
> removable USB key. **Key files may be stored in a similar way and used
> instead of interactive passphrase entry.**
>
> This extension also adds these features:
>
> - allow a crypto volume UUID to be specified with or without embedded hyphens.
> - give the user a second chance to enter a passphrase after failing to unlock a LUKS volume with a given passphrase or key file.
>
> [...]

Instructions are given on how to apply patches to upstream. It would probably be best to integrate the 7 patches mentioned to the SuSe .src.rpm and rebuild the package (with all that it implies: build tools, source dependencies...), but that's out of the scope of this answer.

Caveats:

- I didn't test it.
- work appears to have stopped in 2018, some [forks](https://github.com/johnlane/grub/network/members) are more recent.
- limitation:

> No Automatic Configuration
>
> This extension does not alter Grub’s automated configuration (e.g.
> grub-mkconfig) in any way. Use of the extended options will **require
> manual configuration of grub.cfg**.